# MinGW interactive shell?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, mingw, msys

I see that MinGW shell launches with

```
sh --login -i
```

Another way to launch would be like this

```
sh --login
```

I know that `-i` is for interactive shell, but I am not seeing a difference between the two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive mode is the default if you don't pass a command to run via `-c`, and if the standard input/output streams are mapped to terminals.

So specifying `-i` on the command line is not necessary. It can be in some situations in scripts or when invoking a shell from another program.

See the INVOCATION section in the bash man page:

> An  interactive  shell  is  one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and
>          error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option. [...]